# NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport datasource autowire?

Tags: java, spring

I have a class extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport. well this superclass has a final setDataSource method on it. How can I wire datasource to it using annotation @autowire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use @Autowired on a constructor or on a method with another name. Personally I prefer the latter option.

```
@Autowired 
public MyClass(DataSource dataSource) {
    super();
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}

@Autowired 
public void setDs(DataSource dataSource) {
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: Another solution is to inject template (which is thread-safe!!) instead of configuring `DaoSupport`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21992433/173149

Comment: Should start using \@Inject henceforth, rather than \@Autowired annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is this:

```
    @Autowired
    private DataSource ds;

    @Override
    protected void initDao() throws Exception {
        super.initDao();
        setDataSource(ds);
    }
```