# What is JdbcDaoSupport used for?

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

In Spring, when we are inserting into the database, we can use `JdbcDaoSupport` or not. My question is, what are the advantages in using it and in which circumstances we should use it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to these answers:

- [Proper way to inject parent class dependencies with Spring annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733509/proper-way-to-inject-parent-class-dependencies-with-spring-annotations)
- [spring3-annotation-JdbcDaoSupport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570521/spring3-annotation-jdbcdaosupport)
- [NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport datasource autowire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852418/namedparameterjdbcdaosupport-datasource-autowire)

**JdbcDaoSupport**, **NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport**, **SimpleJdbcDaoSupport** are unnecessary and are mental dust. They doesn't save any line of code because you need to inject data-source or template into.

What I recommend - to create templates in XML/class config per data source and reuse/inject them as templates are thread safe according to docs:

> Once configured, a JdbcTemplate instance is threadsafe. You may want multiple JdbcTemplate instances if your application accesses multiple databases, which requires multiple DataSources, and subsequently multiple differently configured JdbcTemplates.

Compare `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and `YourDaoImpl.java`:

```
public class YourDaoImpl implements YourDao {

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public int tableExists(String table) {
        String sql = "select count(*) from all_tables"
                + "  where table_name = :tbl";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                    sql, new MapSqlParameterSource("tbl", table), Integer.class);
    }
}
```

with `JdbcDaoSupport.java`:

```
public class YourDaoImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements YourDao {

   @Autowired
    public void setDs(DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public int tableExists(String table) {
        String sql = "select count(*) from all_tables"
                + "  where table_name = :tbl";
        return getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate()
               .queryForObject(
                       sql,
                       new MapSqlParameterSource("tbl", table), Integer.class);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE** Official statement about stateless (and so thread safety) of `JdbcTemplate`/`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` here https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11478

Answer (score 9):

First lets point out the [API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html) specifies this class as a convenience class ("support"). I believe JdbcDaoSupport supports, aka provides you with, a base implementation of the [DAO design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) for jdbc whereas a template class (see [template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)) will give you a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that is used to inject into your DAO classes.

In my experience I haven't found a reason to couple my DAO to a *Support class. I instead create my specific jdbcTemplate beans and inject them into my DAO classes favoring composition over inheritence -- generally a good object-oriented practice.

From the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-idioms), "You can choose whether to inherit from this class. The JdbcDaoSupport class is provided as a convenience only.".

As Spring states, **JdbcDaoSupport is a convenience only**. They say nothing about its advantages over using one of the template implementations.